# Getting *http.Request from Context on AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, http, go

I'm using app engine, and creating `context.Context` (golang.org/x/net/context) variable from the `*http.Request`.

```
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
```

I'm passing the context around and I'm trying to figure out a way to get the `*http.Request` from the `context.Context` in order to log the `http.Request`.

I search all over the doc but I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: did you try `c.Request()`?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer golang.org/x/net/context  doesn't contain   Request

Comment: as @icza mentioned, `appengine.NewContext` is not a `golang.org/x/net/context.Context` object, and it has a request member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`appengine.NewContext(r)`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/reference#NewContext) returns a value of type [`appengine.Context`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/reference#Context). This is not the same as the [`Context`](http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/context#Context) type of the [`golang.org/x/net/context`](http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/context) package!

Having a value of type `appengine.Context`, you can't get the `*http.Request` you used to create it. If you will need the `*http.Request`, you have to take care of passing that around yourself (you have it, since you use that to create the context).

Note that `appengine.Context` (which is an interface type) has a method `Context.Request()`, but that is for internal use only, it is not exported for anyone to call it. And also it returns an `interface{}` and not a `*http.Request`. Even if it returns a value holding a `*http.Request`, you can't rely on it as this method may be changed or removed in future versions.

Passing the `*http.Request` along with the `appengine.Context` *is* the best way. Trying to get it from the context is just "wizardry" and might break with a new SDK release. If you want to simplify it, you may create a wrapper struct and pass that wrapper instead of 2 values, for example:

```
type Wrapper struct {
    C appengine.Context
    R *http.Request
}
```

And a helper func:

```
func CreateCtx(r *http.Request) Wrapper {
    return Wrapper{appengine.NewContext(r), r}
}
```

Comment: what will be best way to get the http.requst data besides passing  it?

Comment: @MIkCode Passing it _is_ the best way, but you may create a wrapper to hold the 2 values. See edited answer.

Comment: i think golang.org/x/net/context is used. [appengine.go](https://github.com/golang/appengine/commit/1c3fdc51e1021e4822cf8475c97d3a14a2a6648e#diff-ab414e534b5e27fda475b60d17cbc565R14)